# Remove camera icon from kitkat lock screen?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, motorola-droid, motorola-droid-razr

I have a Droid Razr Maxx HD that just got an OTA update to KitKat. I am wondering if there is a way to remove the camera icon from the lock screen and disable the right-to-left swipe to enable the camera.

I've looked and haven't seen any settings for this... if one even exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom lock screen. [Just pick the one that you like](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/7-top-lock-screen-replacement-apps-for-android-february-2014/)

Comment: Accepted since it looks like you can't do anything to turn it off on the stock one.

Answer (score 0):

The [Lockscreen Policy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordpress.chislonchow.deviceadminkeyguard) app can disable the camera or other widgets from your lock screen.